# Error while attempting to create table MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Error Message >>> 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'XXXXXX', system error: 10038 An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

```
                create_table = list()
                create_table.append("CREATE TABLE " + self.tableName + " (`test1` text")
                customPermission = "test2"
                create_table.append(", `customPermission` text")
                create_table.append(")")
                await self.bot.say("".join(create_table))
                cursor.execute("".join(create_table))
                cursor.close()
                db.close()
```

Actually, that line ("await self.bot.say("".join(create_table))") prints me the whole query and its

```
CREATE TABLE permissions_345624090524123138 (`role` text, `customPermission` text)
```

And I have no idea what can I do to fix that error.
Dont ask why that code has no sense, its not the thing. I want to do something else, but this is the key. Thanks :>

Comment: And its not really a problem with MySQL. I tried something like: create_table = "query_goes_here" and cursor.execute(create_table) and it worked ;x

Comment: How long does it take for your code to reach this query?  Could just be a connection timeout.

Comment: Its not @Devon, its not the point

Comment: I did it, solved :>

Comment: Add an answer then to help future readers.

Comment: It was a mistake in other part of the code, nvm